# Why do I get CORS error with public API from localhost only

Tags: reactjs, api, cors, public

I am using public API for nameday celebrations. I implemented the functionality yesterday and everything was working fine. Today, without any change to the code, it is throwing the CORS error. The thing I do not understand is that if you use the url in the browser (https://api.abalin.net/get/today), you get the JSON response. If I set fetch to mode: 'no-cors', I get this response.

[image: r]

I am using fetch API and I have already tried various CORS options and headers but nothing helped. I also tried the chrome console and it is working fine as well.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: You can't access another domain from localhost. It is cross domain access. In order to make it work you need to allow it from the server.  Alternatively,  you may use jsonp or some other approach in your client code.

Comment: It worked just fine yesterday. The API should not have any CORS blocking policies.

Comment: Use a proxy to make the request...either your own, or a third party service

Comment: I tried invoking this URL from a html file using XMLHttpRequest and it just worked.

Comment: @fiveelements It works everywhere for me as well, except for the react app..

Comment: I have just tried mozilla and it works so it has to do something with chrome. I have tried to clear the site data but it didnt help.

Comment: Code doesn't just magically stop working overnight with no changes. The likely scenario is cached code. However, because we're working with CORS, and what each browser defines as a "simple" call is up to interpretation, it's certainly possible that you have some very specific thing with this request that converts it from a simple request to one that requires a preflight (assuming the server doesn't properly respond to preflights.) Either way.... More information in the question would help, such as the options you are passing to fetch, and the headers sent/returned.

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved the issue. The problem was with the HTTP cache. When I reloaded the cache with `cache: 'reload'` option, it downloaded fresh data. I still don't know why the CORS error happened, though. I will observe the behavior again tomorrow as the nameday changes every day.